# Offline dictionary with pronunciation and usages

Tags: software-recommendation, dictionary

Which is the best offline dictionary for Ubuntu ?

It should be like Cambridge or Oxford dictionaries with pronunciation.

The dictionaries, I found did not have enough examples of the sentence in use nor do they
tell a lot about meaning.

Comment: I suppose there is no more development for such offline dictionary. I currently use [Goldendict](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/goldendict/), needs internet but very good which is currently available.

Answer (score 64):

> **(I).** ***`dict`*** - a CLI client to `dictd` server (offline usage):

*Section - text*

*Installation:*

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

<sup>(to allow Universe repo)</sup>

```
sudo apt-get install dict
sudo apt-get install dictd
```

Installing English dictionary databeses (*gcide, wn, devil*):

```
sudo apt-get install dict-gcide
sudo apt-get install dict-wn
sudo apt-get install dict-devil
```

Installing English Thesaurus database (*moby-thesaurus*):

```
sudo apt-get install dict-moby-thesaurus
```

[It also supports various *translation/bilingual dictionaries*.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380847/is-it-possible-to-translate-words-via-terminal/395357#395357)

**Usage**:

1. Using a particular database (*eg. WordNet - wn*):

   ```
   dict -d wn "dictionary"
   ```
2. Not specifying a dict-database will output definitions/translations/thesaurus from all available databases. eg.

   ```
   dict "dictionary"
   ```

   #### Workaround to include phoneme mnemonics:

   Let's define a function that will use `espeak` for *phoneme mnemonics* and `dict` for definitions, thesauri, and others.

   - First install `espeak` (if it's not already):

     ```
     sudo apt-get install espeak
     ```
   - Open the `.bashrc` file in your user-home directory with text editor of your choice:

     ```
     nano ~/.bashrc
     ```

     or

     ```
     gedit ~/.bashrc &
     ```

     (even better if you place your custom aliases and functions in `~/.bash_aliases` rather than in `~/.bashrc`)
   - Append the following function and save the file:

     ```
     function define {
     # espeak for the pronunciation audible output and phonetic alphabet string
     echo "Phoneme mnemonics: $(espeak -ven-uk-rp -x -s 120 "$1" 2> /dev/null)"       
     # dict - the client for the dictionary server
     dict "$1"       
     }
     ```

     *[here I've used the switches `-ven-uk-rp` for British English Received Pronunciation (`espeak --voices` for more), `-x` to display mnemonics, `-s` for speech output speed. You can modify the switches for `espeak` or `dict` as per your needs.]*
   - Open a new instance of terminal and use `define` to look for definitions. e.g.:

     ```
     define dictionary
     ```

     or

     ```
     define dictionary | less
     ```

     [image: snap_hash]
     *(with `less` you can use arrow keys to scroll through the definitions; pressing `h` will show you some more controls that you can use; to quit press `q`)*

---

> **(II).** ***Gnome Dictionary***:

*Section - Universe/gnome*

*Installation:*

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-dictionary
```

[image: gnome-dictionary_snap]

Note: To use `gnome-dictionary` offline, you should first install a dictionary server and the desired databases (*the installation of `dictd` and some databases are shown in option **(I)** above.*)

After installing `gnome-dictionary`, a dictionary server (e.g. `dictd`) and the databases (e.g. `dict-wn`, `dict-gcide`) you'll have to configure so that it looks up the locally installed server. To do this, start `gnome-dictionary` and from the menu navigate to *Edit -> Preferences*. In the **Dictionary Preferences** window, click <kbd>Add</kbd> button, then in **Add Dictionary Source** add the information about your local dictionary server; add the Description (like *dictd*), the Hostname - **localhost** (or some other in your local network), the Port number to `2628` (`2628` is the default as specified in the DICT Protocol RFC.<sub>excerpt from `dictd` documentation</sub>) and hit the <kbd>Add</kbd> button. Then in Dictionary Preferences window, select *dictd* radio button and close the prefs window. Now you should be able to use it offline.

[image: configGnD4offline]
 [image: selectSourceDictd]

---

> **(III).** ***"Artha"***, *A handy off-line thesaurus based on WordNet*:

*Section - Universe/utils*

*Installation:*

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

<sup>(to allow Universe repo)</sup>

```
sudo apt-get install artha
```

[image: artha_snap]

> **(IV).** ***"GoldenDict"***, offering feature-rich dictionary lookup program using WebKit for an accurate articles' representation, complete with all formatting, colors, images and links.

*Section - Universe/utils*

*Installation:*

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

<sup>(to allow Universe repo)</sup>

```
sudo apt-get install goldendict
```

[image: goldendict_snap]

Comment: Is gnome-dictionary offline?

Comment: @AnwarShah it's not by default, but you can configure it.. I've edited the post to include that. Thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: How do I use the use the define command to give definitions from a specific dictionary (eg: - WordNet).

Comment: GoldenDict requires the same/similar configuration changes as Gnome Dictionary in order for it to work offline.

Answer (score 14):

I have installed Artha,  Good dictionary.  But Artha doesn't provide 'Pronunciation' functionality.

you can install it either from software center or from terminal with

```
sudo apt-get install artha
```

or using graphical Software center [image: Install artha via the software center]

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [Aard Dictionary](http://aarddict.org/index.html).

You can download the *.deb file from the homepage and install any dictionary of your choice. Available dictionaries from the website are: Wikipedia, Wikiquote, Wiktionary, Wikispecies, WordNet, Collaborative International Dictionary of English, Jargon File and Hitchwiki.

You can install as many dictionaries at same time as you want.

I would recommend to try it Wiktionary and Collaborative International Dictionary of English installed and see how it goes.

Btw: It's GPL v3 licenced.

It's also available for Android phones, I currently have the german Wikipedia always with me on my phone.

Comment: This is a kde base dictionary which may require downloading lots of stuff from kde library. But, The dictionary is good I think

Comment: @AnwarShah
I don't think so, as it is written in Python language. Here is a quote from the makefile: 'Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${python:Depends}, python-pyicu (>= 0.8), python-simplejson, python-pkg-resources, python-qt4 (>=4.5)'

Comment: I downloaded and installed it. It is KDE stuff. Do you have kde-desktop installed. If yes, then you'll not informed or alarmed for the huge download.

Comment: Yes, seems I still had installed most KDE ibraries despite removing kde-desktop. My bad. Still, it's a very nice dictionary.

Comment: In 13.10 the dictionary installs without adding too much KDE library. Working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Goldendict with wybbandtts file.

[image: Install Golden dict via the software center]

or From terminal

```
sudo apt-get install goldendict
```

Comment: Adding more details about the process will be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

**XOWA**

You can use WIktionary database offline with this app.

http://gnosygnu.github.io/xowa/

Download  page http://gnosygnu.github.io/xowa/download.html