# Best Offline Dictionary for 14.04 LTS

Tags: dictionary

I have found 1 old thread ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170775/offline-dictionary-with-pronunciation-and-usages)) on this issue. But The thread is nearly 3 years old. I did search using Ubuntus `Software Centre` too. Didn't find anyone which looks 5 stared by hundreds of the Ubuntu users. So finally decided to ask question here. I want to know which offline dictionary is considered best nowadays? And can anyone tell me the installation process via `Terminal`?

Comment: Questions "what is best" are off-topic here as opinion based. You can try ubuntuforums.org to discuss it.

Comment: Golden Dict - The question is off-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dict** - a CLI client to dictd server (offline usage):

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

(to allow Universe repo)

```
sudo apt-get install dict
sudo apt-get install dictd
```

Installing English dictionary databeses (gcide, wn, devil):

```
sudo apt-get install dict-gcide  
sudo apt-get install dict-wn 
sudo apt-get install dict-devil
```

Installing English Thesaurus database (moby-thesaurus):

```
sudo apt-get install dict-moby-thesaurus
```

this is an offline terminal based dictionay.

Comment: I think the answer is same as I red another one which is almost 2 years old. However it seems `dict` is still the first preference for Ubuntu