# How to install Cambridge dictionary without wine?

Tags: dictionary

I'm a very new ubuntu user just turned from windows. I was wondering if I can get the **Cambridge** off-line dictionary without wine ?
Any other easy way to do ?
I know there are alternatives to it but **Cambridge dict.** is the one I'm familiar with in my job so I work on it faster

Comment: Can you explain what's the problem with using WINE?

Comment: It's actually misses up every time I try ( **complicated to install** )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Software not intended for usage on Linux will not work with Linux.

All methods will envolve some sort of usage of Windows where virtualization with VMWare or VirtualBox is the best thing to use. Even far superior to WINE.

The best option to get rid of this (to me ;) ) unhealthy dependency you have on Windows is to take a plunge and try to get the hang of one of our native versions. Or to focus on a version that is independent of operating system.

This is a bit much to go on: https://askubuntu.com/a/417132/15811 but it is worth the effort ;)

Comment: Well. thank you Sir for that information I wish I could rate your answer up but still hates off :)

Comment: The first sentence is not technically correct. An open source software which was never intended for usage on Linux could be re-compiled for Linux depending on how portable the code is (albeit that doesn't apply to the OP's requirement).